# why the return statement is not executing?

Tags: java, binary-tree

I'm trying to implement a find method in a binary tree.
The problem appears when the method needs to return a value but it seems like its not executing that statement even when have other lines in the same semicolon that executes.

```
public String find(Node currentNode, String value)
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        if(currentNode.getData().compareToIgnoreCase(value) == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("current -> "+currentNode.getData()); //showing
            return currentNode.getData(); //not executing
        }

        if(value.compareToIgnoreCase(currentNode.getData()) < 0)
        {
            find(currentNode.getLeft(), value);
        }
        else if(value.compareToIgnoreCase(currentNode.getData()) > 0)
        {
            find(currentNode.getRight(), value);
        }
    }

    return null; //always executing
}
```

i expect "a" but returns null.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Show example input and explain what is happening. Do not just throw code at us. Or worse, incomplete code. Read [ask] and [help], thank you.

Comment: probably you need to add `return ` in front of recursive calls to `find`

Comment: You never do anything with the return value of your `find` calls. You just call it, but dont catch the returned result. You likely intended to `return find(...);`.

Comment: You are calling `find` but not doing anything with its return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the data that returns your recursive call, right now you are ignoring it. Also you always return `null` no matter what, here's a fixed version of the program:

```
public String find(TreeNode currentNode, String value) {
    if (currentNode == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if(currentNode.getData().compareToIgnoreCase(value) == 0) {
        return currentNode.getData(); //not executing
    }

    if (currentNode.getData().compareToIgnoreCase(value) > 0) {
        return find(currentNode.getLeft(), value);
    } else {
        return find(currentNode.getRight(), value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When you execute the line

```
find(currentNode.getLeft(), value);
```

Your statement `return currentNode.getData();` is executing, but you are ignoring what your recursive call has returned.  (Similar for the `getRight()` statement.)  Then the if/else statement completes and the `return null` at the bottom executes.  That is why you are always getting `null`.

Return whatever the recursive call returns, so that the returned value propagates back to the original call properly, e.g.:

```
return find(currentNode.getLeft(), value);
```